# Ocupar el 100% del alto de una pagina

Tags: css, bootstrap

recurro a su ayuda, tengo un menu lateral, el cual necesito que ocupe el 100% del alto de la pagina. Estoy ocupando el formato de columnas que proporciona boostrap, pero resulta ser que si ocupo la propiedad **position:fixed** en la columna que corresponde al menu, la columna de la derecha queda detras y pegada a la izquierda de la ventana, necesito mantener la estructura de las columnas sin que se superpongan, pero que la de izquierda se mantenga ocupando el 100% en lo alto

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 p-0 menu" id="menu">         
            <div class="menu-body">
                <div class="menu-header">
                    <a href="<?php echo $raiz;?>"><img class="mt-2 img-menu" src="<?php echo $raiz;?>imagenes/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                    <i class="icon-cross1 text-white f-30 float-right mt-3 mr-1 d-md-block d-lg-none"></i>          
                </div>
                <div class="menu-perfil">
                    <img src="<?php echo $raiz;?>imagenes/avatar_hombre.png" class="m-3 avatar" alt="..." width="75">
                    <div>
                        <h5 class="m-0 jura">Jonathan Alarcón</h5>                      
                        <p class="m-0"><small><i class="icon-dot-single text-success f-25"></i>Online</small></p>               
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-buscador px-3 py-2">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="buscador_menu" class="label-resp">BUSCAR</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-resp" name="buscador_menu" id="buscador_menu">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>          
                <div class="menu-contenido">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item encabezado p-2">GENERAL</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="<?php echo $raiz;?>portal/ordenes" class="nav-link">Ordenes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="<?php echo $raiz;?>portal/subir-archivos" class="nav-link">Subir Archivos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="<?php echo $raiz;?>portal/comprar-creditos" class="nav-link">Comprar Créditos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="<?php echo $raiz;?>portal/estadisticas" class="nav-link">Estadísticas Vehículos </a>
                        </li>                           
                        <li class="nav-item encabezado p-2">ADMINISTRAR</li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $raiz;?>portal/mi-perfil">Mi Perfil</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Información</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                      
            </div>  
            <div class="menu-footer py-2">
                <ul class="nav text-center">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item" href="#"><i class="icon-bell1"></i><span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning notification">3</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item" href="#"><i class="icon-mail1"></i><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success notification">7</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item" href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item" href="<?php echo $raiz;?>logica/login/cerrar_sesion.php"><i class="icon-log-out"></i></a></li>
                </ul>           
            </div>          
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8">
            <div class="row d-lg-none d-md-block">
                <div class="col-12 p-0">
                    <nav class="header-menu px-3">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $raiz;?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $raiz;?>imagenes/logo-negro.png" width="300" alt="" class="img-header">
                        </a>
                        <button class="btn navbar-toggler float-right mt-2" type="button" id="btn-menu"><i class="icon-menu1 text-black"></i></button>          
                    </nav>  
                </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="row bg-dark my-3 mx-2 rounded text-white p-4">              
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p class="m-0 d-lg-block">BALANCE CRÉDITOS : <span id="creditos"></span></p>
                    <p class="m-0 d-lg-block">ARCHIVOS EN FILA : <span>0</span></p>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                    <p class="m-0">EL TIEMPO ACTUAL PARA EL PROCESAMIENTO DE ARCHIVOS ES APROXIMADAMENTE 30 MIN</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p class="m-0">HORA ACTUAL:</p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block" id="reloj"></p>
                    <p class="d-inline-block" id="fecha"></p>       
                    <p class="d-inline-block">Santiago, Chile</p>                   
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <p class="m-0 f-12 text-center">ESTIMADO CLIENTE, FAVOR SE LE RECOMIENDA GUARDAR LOS ARCHIVOS EN SU COMPUTADOR PERSONAL. NO SOMOS RESPONSABLES DE LA DISPONIBILIDAD PARA LA DESCARGA DE ARCHIVOS DESPUÉS DE 1 MES DE HABER REALIZADO EL PEDIDO</p>          
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Aca los estilos que le aplico al menu.

```
.menu{
    z-index: 1000; 
    background-color: #000000;
    /*left: -100%; 
    display: none;*/ 
    top: 0; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    font-family: 'Jura'; 
    color: #EAEAEA; 
    display: block; 
    height: 100vh; 
    position: fixed
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando usas position fixed el elemento sale del flujo y queda como flotando y el siguiente elemento pasa a ocupar el lugar de este. Prueba asi:

```
.menu{
    z-index: 1000; 
    background-color: #000000;
    /*left: -100%; 
    display: none;*/ 
    top: 0; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    font-family: 'Jura'; 
    color: #EAEAEA; 
    display: block; 
    height: 100vh; 
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

position sticky no saca a los elementos del flujo, lo que hace es que el elemento se desplace desde su posicion hacia arriba cuando haces scroll y cuando llega al tope se pega. Por lo tanto si le pones top:0 ya estara al tope. Espero te funcione!!

Comment: Me a venido a la perfección, muchas gracias estimado.